# Which heatsink size/socket fits on an AMD E350 Zacate?

Tags: heatsink, cpu-cooler

I have the [Jetway NC85-E350-LF](http://www.jetway.com.tw/jw/ipcboard_view.asp?productid=814&proname=NC85-E350-LF) which comes with a tiny fan. For reasons unknown to me yet the CPU of this board runs very hot during simple operations. I've read that idle temperatures around 45C are normal for this CPU but mine seems to start at 45C and go up slowly but steadily until the BIOS decides that the CPU is to hot and enables the fan at full speed and stays there for a very long time. The temperature for this can be set in the BIOS and is now set at 65C. The noise that this tiny fan makes is terrible.

Since there is still some space available in the case around the spot where the CPU is located and there are holes on the side the case that are clearly for airflow out of the case, I'm looking for a replacement heatsink/fan that could fit this board. Which size/socket should I look for that fits the AMD E-350 Zacate, preferably with a fan on side?

I have this [Chieftec Flier FI-02BC](http://www.chieftec.eu/en/chassis/itx-tower/fi-02bc.html) case, which is in upright position. As a result the fan mounting point that you can see in the "right side view" image in the gallery is on top of the case and practically next to the CPU. Preferably I'd mount a fan there that can cool the CPU and remove the CPU fan. If possible I'd also replace the heatsink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. #1 – replace the fan. I'm using mini-ITX Zacate board with 12cm low-RPM fan and it's inaudible. I didn't bother with fan mounting, it is just put on the heatsinks:
   [image: babča - AMD Zacate HTPC - babčův píseček]
   Original fan was a nightmare:[image]
2. You can replace heatsink, but it's not a standard operation on Atom/Zacate boards. 
   According to [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zedriq/5840050277/sizes/l/in/photostream/) picture, distance between APU heatsink holes is ~42mm, so you can search for some aftermarket chipset heatsink with 42mm or universal mounting and max height of 80mm.
   Thermalright HR-05 / IFX, Primecooler PC-NBHP1 could fit you APU, but it seems both of them are too big for your case :( (Other heatsinks I found are too small for the replace to take effect.)

Comment: I share your thoughts about the "original fan" :D

Comment: btw the 12cm fan on picture above is 800RPM Scythe KAZE-JYUNI Slim SL with RPM lowered to ~550, I can recommend it!

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'll certainly look for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, boards with soldered onboard CPUs typically don't have a standard CPU cooler hole pattern. I highly doubt that you will be able to find an aftermarket cooler designed specifically for this board or CPU.

You haven't stated which case you are using. You will probably have better luck increasing the cooling with larger case fan, rather than trying to improve the CPU cooler, but it's hard to know without more information.

Because of the small CPU die size, we have seen a lot of overheating issues with the AMD embedded CPUs. You could try to find a heat spreader material, such as eGraf: http://graftechaet.com/eGRAF/eGRAF-Products/SPREADERSHIELD-3-D-Heat-Spreaders.aspx

Or, you might simply try a higher quality thermal paste.